# what type of machine learning or neural net algorithm would i use for predictions about the shape of a plot

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, continuous-time

if a data set is set up such that it has 5 independent variables and an array of 201 elements of "smooth continuous" data as the dependent variable. I was wondering if there was a model optimized to handle a situation like that. And what form would I provide the data in.

Here is an example of how the data would look. Each data plot has 5 parameters that relate to it. Id like a model where I can input values for those 5 elements and it produces a prediction for the corresponding data. So instead of just finding the relationship between the 5 independent variables and the 201 separate array elements, it somehow finds the relationship between the independent variables, and more generally, the shape of the data plot, if that's possible?

[image]

If what I'm asking makes sense and it is possible, some guidance on the type or types of models to look into would be appreciated, thanks all, I'm working in Matlab as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some sense, this seems like a pretty standard supervised learning problem. You have features that predict the shape of the plot. You have five characteristics that determine the shape of the plot. Use the features to predict those five characteristics in a multivariate regression. Now, multivariate regression with a five-variable outcome makes for complicated statistics (for instance, how are the five values related), but that seems like the core of your problem and a possible starting point.

It seems, however, like your main goal is to predict the value of the `data` at a particular `time`. If that is the case, it would seem like you could use `time` as an additional feature, perhaps interacted with the original features, to predict the `data` value instead of the five plot parameters. [functional-data-analysis](/questions/tagged/functional-data-analysis) might prove useful for this.